# Failure to find org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:jar:1.3.1 in

Tags: maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I have had this error these days and I have no idea what it could be, if it is because of the older version of the project or because I leave the error here, the technologies are:

JEE 6,
JBoss 7.1,
PrimeFaces 3.2,
EJB 3.1,
JPA 2.0,
JAAS

Here the error in detail:

Failure to find org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:jar:1.3.1 in http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo was cached 
 in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-annotation-plugin has elapsed or updates are forced

Here I leave the pom of the error:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>traceable</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.traceable.commodities</groupId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>traceable-model</artifactId>
<name>modelo</name>
<description>Proyecto que contiene el modelo de entidades para la plataforma de traceable commodities</description>

<properties>
    <!-- ENCODING PROPERTIES -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

</properties>

<!-- Plugin Repositories -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-annotation-plugin</id>
        <url>http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
        <name>JBoss Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<!-- BUILD -->
<build>
    <!-- PLUGINS -->
    <plugins>

        <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <!-- Disable annotation processing for the compiler plugin, since the 
                    one will be done by the maven-processor-plugin. -->
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- just put generated artifacts where the entities are -->
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/metamodel/</outputDirectory>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-processor-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.3.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>process</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: So if you remove PrimeFaces from the project, this maven error is gone?

Comment: no, it is not solved by removing primefaces

Comment: So the question is not PrimeFaces related then

Comment: It is not from a plugin that does not have more support and I would like to know why you can change that plugin

Comment: Then check where it is actualy needed, check if it is available somewhere, check about the 'retry'error